# $_SESSION does not exist unless dumped?

Tags: php, session

I have a page that was working just fine and dandy with sessions. I installed memcached php package and now for some reason the session data is not saving....unless dumped.

So calling `echo $_SESSION['bank'];` in my code results in no output. However When I `var_dump($_SESSION);` it gives me the output of

```
array(1) { ["bank"]=> string(2) "11" }
```

And even more od, is when it is dumped, the `$_SESSION['bank']` variable works! I commented out the dump, and back to not working.

**EDIT** for code:

session setting include:

```
session_start();
$sub = explode('/',$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$sub = $sub[2];
$_SESSION['bank']=$sub;
```

Then I am trying to access it via:

```
<? session_start(); ?>
Youre session is: <?=$_SESSION['bank'];?>
```

I get:
`Your session is:`

HOWEVER

```
<?
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
echo 'Youre session is: ' . $_SESSION['bank'];
?>
```

Gives:

```
array(1) { ["bank"]=> string(2) "11" }
Youre session is: 11
```

Comment: what does $a = $_SESSION['bank'] . '_content'; echo $a; say

Comment: you have to echo out the value `echo $_SESSION["bank"];`

Comment: Are you running `session_start`?

Comment: @marabutt it gives me what I wanted `11_content` but when changing your code to `echo $_SESSION['bank']."_content";` I just get `_content` ...what gives?

Comment: @Orangepill I am echoing the session variable, it works when the session is dumped.

Comment: Is memcache configured properly? http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.sessions.php - you can try turning it back to "files" and see if it works - http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-handler

Comment: Would you be willing to post your code with context? Your post does not yet contain enough information to reveal the problem.

Comment: Sanity check: Are you sure it's not actually being posted inside a HTML tag that's hiding it by accident?

Comment: @GeorgeCummins edited with code.

Comment: @slugonamission thanks for the check, but I made sure to view source and try to find it anywhere :(

Comment: I still see nothing that would distinguish between the two. The only thing that gives me pause is the short-open tags, but if the code from your working example is indeed working as posted, we can safely assume that you have short-open tags enabled.

Comment: So, I got a micky-mouse way around it, right after my `session_start()` I added `echo "<span style='display:none;'>".session_id()."</span>";` Don't know why that works, but it does. I changed no other piece of my code.

Comment: That sounds like some sort of output buffering issue. In both cases, it worked after you generated some output. Are you doing any intentional buffering?

Comment: No I am not. Like I said, everything worked great until the installation of memcached.